# ubuntu&win8 dual boot from ssd. Grub sometimes works, sometimes not

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, ssd

The situation is quite complex.

I have a thinkpad x230. I recovered windows 8 to a msata SSD, and install Ubuntu 12.04 in the same SSD. I have used boot-repair to fix the boot problem(By the way, it tells me buggy kernel is detected). The computer use UBFI to boot.

Now, sometimes the grub menu is correct and after I choose a system, it boots.

Sometimes no options in the grub menu at all.

And sometimes, the options are correct, but after I select one, the screen goes black and forever.

It drives me crazy!

Comment: Did you remember to disable Window's 'fast boot' option?

Comment: No, is that necessary and the reason to my problem?

Comment: Could be, you can read [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187888) and most [guides](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/164891) that explain the installation of Ubuntu with Win 8 explains why this is.